# Passing any value over cancel channel causes program to hang

Tags: go

I am trying to use worker goroutines to check diameters out to a certain distance, it works great when I do one tile at a time, but when I do a bunch, there is a massive slow down. I figure this is because a lot of goroutines are still running even though they are no longer needed. I added a fail channel to tell all running goroutines to close up shop, but doing this causes the app to hang. Actually, passing any value to the channel causes the app to hang, even if I don't consume it.

```
 caught := 0
loop:
    for angle := float64(0); angle < 360; angle++ {
        select {
        case <-failChannel:
            break loop
        default:
         log.Print(angle)
        }

    }
    channelOut <- []int{radius, caught}
```

is the routine that uses the channel

```
for {
        select {
        case circle := <-channelOut:
            if circle[1] == 0 {
                radiusMap[circle[0]] = 0
                if _, radius := testLine(radiusMap); radius <= circle[0] {
                    failChannel <- 0


                }
            } else {
                radiusMap[circle[0]] = 1

            }

        default:    
        }
    }
```

Is the loop that will pass the int to the failChannel. I am doing an int channel because I want to see if a lower radius failed, and if so stop. I made it just any int right now as a test.

Does anyone have any clue why this would be hanging? It doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Please shrink your code to the minimum and provide full working sample (including calls to the routines). All the circle/radius stuff is not related to the channels.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have more than one goroutine that's counting on that failchannel, you'll have an issue. Only one of those channel receivers will get the fail notification, not all.

Comment: how do you initialize fail channel? is it buffered? an unbuffered channel will result in a hang.

Comment: it's because your producer routine never ends, and it will reach a point where nobody consumes `fail` anymore. If your `fail` is unbuffered, your producer will be blocked, and thus hang.

Comment: oh, @MitchellIngram good to know you fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can close a channel to signal completion:

```
failed := make(chan struct{})
select {
case <-failed:
}
```

In another goroutine:

```
close(failed)
```

Will cause the `failed` case to happen. This will work with any number of goroutines listening on `failed`. Be careful to only do this once though, because closing an already close channel will panic. You could use this pattern:

```
// A Stopper signals completion over C by closing it when Stop is called
type Stopper struct {
    C    chan struct{}
    once sync.Once
}

// NewStopper creates a new Stopper
func NewStopper() *Stopper {
    return &Stopper{
        C: make(chan struct{}),
    }
}

// Stop closes C. It is safe to call multiple times
func (s *Stopper) Stop() {
    s.once.Do(func() {
        close(s.C)
    })
}
```